# Is $\log^{*}(\log(n)) = \Theta (\log(\log^{*}(n)))$?

Tags: asymptotics

Which one is asymptotically larger? $\log^*(\log(n))$ or $\log(\log^*(n))$? I think they are asymptotically tight bounds for each other (one is $\Theta$ of the other).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose that $\log^* n = k$. This means it takes $k$ many $\log$'s to reduce $n$ below some constant. Therefore $\log^* \log n = k-1$ (assuming $k$ is not too small), whereas $\log \log^* n = \log k$.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose $f_1(n)=\log \log^{*}(n)$, and $f_{2}(n)=\log^{*} \log(n)$.

Let $n=2^m$ then
According the definition of iterated function:

> $\log^* n$ (usually read "log star"), is the number of times the logarithm function must be iteratively applied before the result is less than or equal to 1.

So
$$f_1(2^m)=\log \log^*(2^m)=\log \log^*\log(2^m)+1=\log\log^*m+1=\theta(\log\log^*m)$$

and
$$f_2(2^m)=\log^*\log(2^m)=\log^*(m)+1=\theta(\log^*m)$$
Finally, for sufficient large $n$ (i.e. as $n\to \infty$) we conclude that:
$$f_1(2^m)=O(f_2(2^m)).$$
Because  let $\log^*(m)=k$ then:
$$f_1(2^m)=\log k$$
and
$$f_2(2^m)=k.$$
Obviously order of growth two mentioned function follow below relation  $$f_1(2^m)=O(f_2(2^m)).$$